# creating and building new package like hector_slam

Tags: slam, navigation, build, hector-slam, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I need to modify hector-slam (odom_frame and base_frame) for my situation which is i dont have a robot system i only have lms100 laser scanner. so i know i should create a new package includes hector_slam and modify inside.

I looked and tried before: the create/build a package tutorials. But now i'm a bit confused when it comes to create a new hector_slam package. It includes so many dependencies, different folders like hector_slam_launch, hector_mapping.

should i follow the create/build package tutorials one by one? in catkin_ws when create a package, the name of it should be the same with hector_slam or not?

and when i run  catkin_create_pkg command, should i write 12 dependencies after that command (which i looked dependecies in http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam)

what is the proper way to follow? or is there another (much easier) way to do that? Like can i use roscp command for copying the files in a new folder and modify them?

Sorry I have a lot of questions in my mind, i hope i can explain myself properly

Thanks, Basak

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234303/creating-and-building-new-package-like-hector_slam/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-05-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-05-13**:
You most likely don't need to modify the source code. You just need to configure/parametrize `hector_slam` and possibly run a `static_transform_publisher`. Look into it and let me know if you get stuck. (I have to run so I can't go into details right now, sorry.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You dont need to modify entire package and rebuild it, just modifying the launch files and setting proper parameters will do.
Have a look at this project
[hector_slam_example](https://github.com/DaikiMaekawa/hector_slam_example)

---

Originally posted by [gp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26916/gp/) with karma: 166 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0